# Style Highchart line chart from psd

Tags: highcharts

I found a clean and simple line chart [psd](http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/clean-simple-line-chart-psd/)

I want to create with Highchart library.

This is that i created at this moment http://jsfiddle.net/pFCgz/1/

but I don't know how create the bullon marker like the psd.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/aFD6a/).

I leave the color matching and font size to you. The general idea is to use the info found [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip) like so:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.y + ' €';
        },
        backgroundColor: 'Grey',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#AAA',
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'White'

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
So it looks like there only a few pre-made symbols for point markers. See [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point-marker). You can create your own, of course. Or, you can edit these existing symbols to achieve what you want. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-fillcolor/)!

Comment: Thanks wergeld for the code of the legnd, but I if you show the circle marker is little different from the psd to my code, the psd has a white center.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, thought you meant the balloon tooltip. My mistake. A quick search leads me to believe you may have to "roll your own".

Comment: @jomarmen, updated answer with solution that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks other time, do you know how could I configure the chart for the  first point of the serie started at the beginning of the grid. Now there are a little whitespace.

Comment: Is this a different question or did my answer break your chart formatting?

Comment: Look how start the first point of the psd, I want created a chart more exactly from psd.

Comment: Okay, it looks like what you need is pointStart (http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-line--pointStart) or min (http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--min). But, because your xAxis is category based it is not as simple (if you were to do a time-based xAxis that would be easier but more stuff to do in the series data elements).